# function rt_lookup( ) undefined

Tags: c, matlab, makefile, simulink, rtw

I used Real time workshop to generate c code from a simulink model. When I tried to compile the resultant C code, I get the above error. When I check in the MODEL.c file, the function rt_lookup is called, but not defined.

After some research in google, I found that lookup tables are used if your model has subsystems.(Yes my model has some subsystems) but no information on this error.

I believe this function is defined in some library file. Any inputs regarding this is really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32253-static-functions-in-real-time-workshop

Comment: If you are compiling the generating code separately in an IDE for example, as opposed to part of the build process, you should probably check out the Pack N Go functionality. See http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2008/11/26/wheres-the-code/

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for your help. I was able to resolve this issue by adding the files rt_look.c and rt_look1d.c in the path. The function rt_lookup( ) is defined in these files.